# Advice Please! - Google Drive Realtime Playground

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Some advice would be appreciated.

I am trying to install the Google drive Realtime playground onto the online Google App Engine. (as well as trying to get it working on my Localhost.

Once uploaded, it renders but all functionality is greyed out. Link to example: https://alpha-113.appspot.com

I have added the client id and app id as stated (within the readme) into the correct .js file and updated the app.yaml file to include the application name.

I am stumped.. Can anyone assist?

James

Answer (score 0):

If you view the output in the Javascript console, you see that you have a number of errors in your javascript.  It looks like the underlying problem is that your CLIENT_ID has invalid syntax.  It should just be the number.  You can't have "."'s in a value in javascript like that.

Comment: Hi cheryl, please could you clarify, is it (1) the client id should be trimmed to just the number, (2) the long client id is fine, but needs to be quoted because it's a string, or (3) either coz google will figure it out. I've seen inconsistent references to both 1 and 2, so a definitive answer would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi do you have single quotes around both your CLIENT_ID and APP_ID ?